# How i can set style for a class with prototype?

Tags: prototype

How can I change the style for a class with a prototype?  What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;" class="rooms" id="room_1"> example</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function rang(image) 
{

   $$('.rooms').setStyle({
     backgroundColor: '#000',
     backgroundImage:  'url('+image+')'

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$$ return an array of objects. So you need to iterate over all html elements:

```
$$('.rooms').each(function(elt) {
  elt.setStyle({
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    backgroundImage:  'url('+image+')'

  });
});
```